# How can i fix the valueerror parameters are of unsupported types

Tags: python, sqlite

```
    def remove(self, id):
        print(id)
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('company.db')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM bikes WHERE rowid=?", (id))
        self.conn.commit()

def remove_bike():
    print(selected_item)
    db.remove(db,selected_item[0])
    clear_text()
    populate_list()
```

The code was working fine just now but when i added rowid to the code below then it started giving me errors

```
def fetch(self, bike_modelnumber):
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect('company.db')
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
    self.cur.execute(
        "SELECT rowid, * FROM bikes WHERE bike_modelnumber LIKE ?", ('%'+bike_modelnumber+'%',))
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    return rows
```

Comment: i dont think you can use both `*` and a specific column name at the same time

Comment: you can use the table name in your selected colomns :
`SELECT bikes.rowid, bikes.* FROM bikes WHERE ... `

Comment: That doesnt work it'll just mess up another part of the code